# Natural spline term in GAM

Tags: r, splines, smoothing

Is it advisable to use natural regression spline basis? I learned that in R the supported smoothers in `gam` are the `lo`, `s`, and `random` only based on the result of the `gam.smooth.list` in `$slist`. Is there any reason why natural spline is not included or is it just the settings of `gam` function in R?

What I'm trying to say is that most of the time what I see is like this

```r
gam.fit = gam(Outstate~Private+s(Room.Board,df=3)+s(Terminal,df=3)+s(perc.alumni,df=3)+s(Expend,df=3)+s(Grad.Rate,df=3), data=College.train)
```

but not

```r
gam.fit = gam(Outstate~Private+ns(Room.Board,df=3)+ns(Terminal,df=3)+ns(perc.alumni,df=3)+ns(Expend,df=3)+ns(Grad.Rate,df=3), data=College.train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use natural splines in regression, if this is what you want. However, notice an important difference between defining terms with s () and using ns () in gam. In the first case what you are fitting is a penalized spline model while in the second just regression splines, i.e. splines without penalty. See also the choices of the lower rank smoothers that you have in s ().

I don't know why natural splines are not included in gam. Perhaps you can ask Simon Wood to include them in the next update..